# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value play audio files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am using tableview which shows list of songs on right side one play button is available when clicking on that play button song will play code for that is as follows

```
func playSelectedSong(sender:UIButton) {
    if sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal) == "Play" {
        sender.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        if player != nil {
            player.stop()
        }
    } else {
        if player != nil {
            if player.playing {
                player.stop()

                var cell = tblSongsList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: lastPlayIndex, inSection: 0))
                var btn:UIButton = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(11) as UIButton
                btn.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            }
        }
        sender.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        var playIndex = sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Selected)?.toInt()
        var itemcolletion:MPMediaItemCollection! = arrData.objectAtIndex(playIndex!) as MPMediaItemCollection
        if itemcolletion != nil {
            var item:MPMediaItem! = itemcolletion.representativeItem as MPMediaItem
            if item != nil {
                var itemURL:NSURL! = item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as NSURL
                if itemURL != nil {
                    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:itemURL , error: nil)
                    if player != nil {
                        player.prepareToPlay()
                        player.play()
                        lastPlayIndex = playIndex!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it gives crash some time. normally after 10 - 15 songs.please help me.

Comment: On what statement does it crash?

Comment: at this line      var itemURL:NSURL! = item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as NSURL

Comment: Check my answer. I think the problem is the forced unwrapping using "as"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing all your implicitly wrapped optionals to optionals and trying. For eg. change

```
var itemcolletion:MPMediaItemCollection! = arrData.objectAtIndex(playIndex!) as MPMediaItemCollection
if itemcolletion != nil {
    var item:MPMediaItem! = itemcolletion.representativeItem as MPMediaItem
    if item != nil {
```

to

```
var itemcolletion:MPMediaItemCollection? = arrData.objectAtIndex(playIndex!) as? MPMediaItemCollection
if itemcolletion != nil {
    var item:MPMediaItem? = itemcolletion!.representativeItem as? MPMediaItem
    if item != nil {
```

As you can see, itemCollection and item are now optionals. Previously you were forced casting them using "as" but now you can use "as?" and check the value before using it.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: it gives error : 'MPMediaItemCollection?' does not have a member named 'representativeItem'

Comment: Yeah that would be preferable...Please upload it on Onedrive/Dropbox etc.

Comment: I should mention though that you will need to unwrap your itemCollection to access it's properties after you have verified that it is not nil using the if loop. You can access the properties using itemcolletion!.representativeItem as? MPMediaItem . It is giving you an error because itemCollection is an optional which needs to be unwrapped. You can also access the value using itemcolletion?.representativeItem as? MPMediaItem in which case it will not crash but simply return nil

Comment: Did you try accessing the property as itemcolletion?.representativeItem or itemcolletion!.representativeItem?

Comment: Is the error coming on the itemcolletion.representativeItem line?